# I don't want knobby tires

Tags: wheels

I have trek 3700 with 26X2 knobbytires on them. I do not intend to ever go off road again. What is the thinnest size tire I can put on. I don't know what size my rims are but everything is standard on the bike.

Thank you, 
Chris

Comment: As always, refer to [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html). Measure you rim internal width, and use his chart for a guide. If anything, go up a size from the minimum, as (despite much misinformation) width and rolling resistance are not significantly related (unless you are a tour rider where seconds/hour are important).

Comment: Bigger tires are nicer in that they are often more comfortable. I'd go for a 26x1.75 probably.

Comment: Of course, you can get relatively smooth tires in pretty much any width (except perhaps the 4-inch size). But without knowing your rim width, 1.75 is probably a safe width, as Batman suggests.  (But note that if you want to reduce rolling resistance you should run a relatively high pressure -- probably 50-75psi on a 1.75, and proportionally higher as you go narrower.)

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming you have the Bontrager AT-650? That is the current wheel set from what I can see. You should *theoretically* be able to go down all the way to 23mm on those, as from what I've been able to see the rim width should be ~19mm.

If you would want to is a different matter. Super skinny tires on a hybrid/mountain bike just seems off to me. When I converted my MTB to a more roadworthy bike I put 28mm slicks on and these were a good mix of comfort and speed IMO.